# Why is my rendered image not showing the view I expect to see using gluLookAt?

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

The task I want to solve is straight-forward: Load a texturized OBJ file and display it such that it takes up a maximum amount of image space. There is no need to rotate the mesh as long as the camera is looking down the negative z-axis and the y-axis is the up vector. I am using pyglet to do that.

To set the camera to the desired position, I am doing the following (code see below): Compute a bounding sphere of the mesh, which is defined by the center of the mesh and the radius to the point farthest away from the center. Then I compute the frustum as explained e.g. [here](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm) and set up an orthogonal projection accordingly. Then I use `gluLookAt` to update the modelviewmatrix like this: The camera sits on the positive z-axis, looks towards the center of the mesh and the y-axis is the up-vector.

The problem is that my rendered image does not look at all like I would expect it to be, e.g. the center of the mesh is not in the center of the image, as you can see in the following image. The image shows the bounding box and the coordinate axes originating from the computed center of the mesh (red: x-axis, green: y-axis, blue: z-axis).

[image]

The code to set up the camera is:

```
    # get the bounding sphere
    center, radius = self._mesh.compute_bounding_sphere()
    diam = radius*2.0

    print 'center:'
    print center
    print 'radius: %f' % radius

    # set up near and far clipping plane
    z_near = 1.0
    z_far = z_near + diam

    # construct params for orthographic projection matrix
    left = center[0] - radius
    right = center[0] + radius
    bottom = center[1] - radius
    top = center[1] + radius

    # if we are not rendering a square image, must correct for aspect ratio
    aspect_ratio = float(self.width) / float(self.height)
    if aspect_ratio < 1.0:
        bottom /= aspect_ratio
        top /= aspect_ratio
    else:
        left *= aspect_ratio
        right *= aspect_ratio

    print 'znear %f, zfar %f' % (z_near, z_far)
    print 'left %f, right %f' % (left, right)
    print 'bottom %f, top %f' % (bottom, top)

    # specify a parallel projection with clipping planes as computed above
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, z_near, z_far)
    # gluPerspective(50.0, aspect_ratio, z_near, z_far)

    # construct a viewing transform as follows: we look at the center of the mesh, the eye is located on the
    # positive z-axis, and the 3D y-axis is the up-vector, i.e. it will be mapped to the y-axis in image space.
    eye = center[2] + radius
    print 'eye:'
    print eye
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, eye, center[0], center[1], center[2], 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

which prints

```
center:
[ 8.51203675 -1.95199815  0.35396978]
radius: 10.462382
znear 1.000000, zfar 21.924764
left -1.950345, right 18.974419
bottom -12.414380, top 8.510384
eye:
10.8163515441
```

Can you help me identify what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no need to rotate the mesh as long as the camera is looking down the negative z-axis and the y-axis is the up vector.

Your camera isn't looking down the `z` axis:

> ```
> gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, eye, center[0], center[1], center[2], 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
> ```

This will introduce a rotation so that the camera direction in world space will be `(center[0], center[1], center[2] - eye) =  (center[0], center[1], -radius)`.

Since you already shift the view volume according to your object, the lookAt point will *not* be the point that will appear at the center of the screen. What you actually need to do is just looking along `-z`, you only need to translate the camera along `+z`:

```
gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, eye, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Note that conceptually, you don't need a view matrix at all for your use case. you could just caclulate the axis-aliged bounding box enclosing your object, and could directly use that as the parameters for your view volume (just like you did with `x` and `y`, but for some, reason, not for `z`). The only trick would be that you need to negate the values for `near` and `far`, because the way `glOrtho` is designed.